# how to do group by on certain fields only in sql

Tags: sql, group-by

I have the following query

```
select a,b,sum(c) from(
   select a,b,c from table 1
   union
   select a,b,c from table 2
)
group by a,b
```

result of above sql is as follows:

```
A        B      C    
Apple   Red    100
Apple   null   100
Pear    Green  200
Pear    null   300
```

instead of above result how can i get the following result:

```
A        B      C
Apple    Red    200
Pear     Green  500
```

Comment: If there are both red and green apples, how should apples with unknown (null) color be counted?

Comment: @Lennart it doesnt matter.. as long as its Apple it should b grouped together. At least for my case. :)

Answer (score 0):

Given your desired results, you want to `GROUP BY` your first column (`A`) and have a single value for your second column (`B`).  You can use another aggregate such as `max` on the second column and remove it from the `GROUP BY`:

```
select a,max(b),sum(c) from(
   select a,b,c from table1
   union
   select a,b,c from table2
) t
group by a
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ca9b/1)

*Note, if you have multiple distinct non-null values per group, this will sum them all to a single max group.*